# How do I get my lollipop tablet to communicate with my win 7 laptop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, windows, usb-connection-mode

When I attach my win 7 laptop to my lollipop android tablet via USB, nothing happens.
I have googled and found various posts suggesting that I have to load the proper device drivers.

However:

1. I am not sure which device requires the drivers and
2. I can't understand how to load the drivers.

I seem to have loaded it properly on the tablet, but when I try to find where to load it on my win 7 machine, and go to device manager, although the devices are connected, there is no sign of it in the device manager.

When I insert an external USB drive into lollipop, the drive works.

Any help here?

Comment: It's your win 7. It requires the drivers to communicate with your tablet and since it's not present, it is unable to detect it.Can u tell which tablet you are using?

Comment: Thank you for responding - it's an RCA Viking Pro 10 - RCT6303W870K.